# Procedure or function has too many arguments specified error

Tags: .net, sql-server-2008, stored-procedures

[Pic of Page on which clicked i get the error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/SwYKp.jpg)

I was going through some projects for reference and while running a project i got the following error 
**Procedure or function HOUSE_INSERT has too many arguments specified.**

Here is the .NET Code

```
     using System;
     using System.Collections.Generic;
     using System.Linq;
     using System.Web;
     using System.Web.UI;
     using System.Web.UI.WebControls;

   public partial class Admin_AddHouse : System.Web.UI.Page
 {
   DS_SOCIETY.SOCIETY_SELECTDataTable SDT = new DS_SOCIETY.SOCIETY_SELECTDataTable();
DS_SOCIETYTableAdapters.SOCIETY_SELECTTableAdapter SAdapter = new DS_SOCIETYTableAdapters.SOCIETY_SELECTTableAdapter();

DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable HDT = new DS_HOUSE.HOUSE_SELECTDataTable();
DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter HAdapter = new DS_HOUSETableAdapters.HOUSE_SELECTTableAdapter();
protected void Page_Load(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    lblmsg.Text = "";
    if (Page.IsPostBack == false)
    {

        SDT = SAdapter.Select_Society();
        drpsociety.DataSource = SDT;
        drpsociety.DataTextField = "SName";
        drpsociety.DataValueField = "sid";
        drpsociety.DataBind();
        drpsociety.Items.Insert(0, "SELECT");
        //HDT = HAdapter.SelectHouse();
        //GridView1.DataSource = HDT;
        //GridView1.DataBind();
    }
}
protected void btnadd_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{

    if (Convert.ToInt32(txtblockname.Text) > Convert.ToInt32(ViewState["home"].ToString()))
    {
        lblmsg.Text = "BlockNo must be less than total no of house";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Red;
    }
    else
    {

        SDT = SAdapter.Select_By_SID(Convert.ToInt32(drpsociety.SelectedValue));

        HAdapter.Insert(Convert.ToInt32(txtblockname.Text), drptype.SelectedItem.Text, txtdetai.Text, drpsociety.SelectedItem.Text, SDT.Rows[0]["image"].ToString());
        lblmsg.Text = "House Added Successfully";
        lblmsg.ForeColor = System.Drawing.Color.Green;
        txtblockname.Text = "";
        txtdetai.Text = "";
        drptype.SelectedIndex = 0;


        SDT = SAdapter.Select_By_SID(Convert.ToInt32(drpsociety.SelectedValue));
        lblhome.Text = "Total House - " + SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString();

        HDT = HAdapter.Select_BY_SNAME(drpsociety.SelectedItem.Text);
        if (HDT.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblallocate.Text = "Allocated House - 0"; lblrem.Text = "Remaining House - " + SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int rem = Convert.ToInt32(SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString()) - HDT.Rows.Count;
            lblrem.Text = "Remaining House - " + rem.ToString();
            lblallocate.Text = "Allocated House - " + HDT.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }
    }
}
protected void drpsociety_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (drpsociety.SelectedIndex == 0)
    {
        lblhome.Text = "";
        lblallocate.Text = "";
        lblrem.Text = "";
    }
    else
    {

        SDT = SAdapter.Select_By_SID(Convert.ToInt32(drpsociety.SelectedValue));
        lblhome.Text = "Total House - " + SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString();
        ViewState["home"] = SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString();

        HDT = HAdapter.Select_BY_SNAME(drpsociety.SelectedItem.Text);
        if (HDT.Rows.Count == 0)
        {
            lblallocate.Text = "Allocated House - 0";
            lblrem.Text = "Remaining House - " + SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString();
        }
        else
        {
            int rem = Convert.ToInt32(SDT.Rows[0]["nohouse"].ToString()) - HDT.Rows.Count;
            lblrem.Text = "Remaining House - " + rem.ToString();
            lblallocate.Text = "Allocated House - " + HDT.Rows.Count.ToString();
        }

    }
  }
 }
```

and here is the SQL 2008 statement used for creating the stored procedure

```
ALTER PROCEDURE [dbo].[HOUSE_INSERT]

@BlockNo int,
@Type nvarchar(50),
@Detail nvarchar(200),
@SName nvarchar(50)

AS
BEGIN

SET NOCOUNT ON;

insert into dbo.HouseMst ( BlockNo,Type,Detail,SName) values (@BlockNo,@Type,@Detail,@SName)
END
GO
```

Comment: Based upon what I'm seeing, you have five parameters you're passing into house_insert, but house_insert is only allowing four parameters.

Comment: yes because the page which was getting the error had 4 parameters and so i made the stored procedure accordingly. I have added the pic of the page at the beginning now.

Comment: What is the code of _HAdapter.Insert_? Here you pass 5 parameters but we can't see what happens next

Comment: i haved added the full code now for that page.

Comment: After adding it, is it working now?

Comment: no its the same error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Procedure or function expects parameter which was not supplied error](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44863548/procedure-or-function-expects-parameter-which-was-not-supplied-error)